# Extend Google app script timeout by default (6 minutes) to 10 minutes

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

When I run the script after 6 min show ...

> [ message: Statement canceled due to timeout or client request (line 140, file "Code")Dismiss ] and stop compiling. I need to insert 2000 row but it only inserts 1200 row. how can I solve that problem?

CODE:

```
function writeManyRecords() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  conn.setAutoCommit(false);

  var start = new Date();
  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO test_table'
      + '(Item, Quantity, Price, total_price) values (?, ?, ?, ?)');


var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();

  for(n=1;n<values.length;++n){
    var cell_1 = values[n][0] ;    
    var cell_2 = values[n][1] ; 
    var cell_3 = values[n][2] ;
    var cell_4 = values[n][3] ;

    stmt.setString(1, cell_1);
    stmt.setString(2, cell_2);
    stmt.setString(3, cell_3);
    stmt.setString(4, cell_4);
    stmt.addBatch();
  }

  var batch = stmt.executeBatch();
```

//**that Line: Statement cancelled due to timeout or client request (line 140, file "Code")**

```
  conn.commit();
  conn.close();

  var end = new Date();
  Logger.log('Time elapsed: %sms for %s rows.', end - start, batch.length);
}
```

Comment: can you split it into two consecutive batches?

Comment: It is not possible to increase the execution time of Google App Script, you'll have to revamp the code to insert data in batches. One solution is to create triggers in Google App Script.

Comment: i create triggers in Google App Script but result is same....1300 row insert then stop compile. But need to insert 2000 row in database.

Comment: The triggers would process the data in batches so you need to keep track of what's already inserted

Comment: how to track inserted data? @Robin Gertenbach

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple utility function you can use to batch your data processing:

```
function isTimeUp_(starttime) {
  var now = new Date();
  return now.getTime() - starttime.getTime() > 270000; // 4.5 minutes
}

function myLongFunction() {
  var starttime = new Date();
  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if (isTimeUp_(starttime )) {
      Logger.log("Time up, finished on row " + i);
      break;
    }
    // rest of the loop if false
  }
}
```

Checking a time shorter than 6 minutes guarantees you won't timeout. Pair this with a trigger to restart the function automatically and pick up on the data processing.

Comment: i can't pair it...can you help me.. @ Brian Bennett